# How to merge from multiple field of access database to one column fo datagridview in vb.net using dataset

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How to convert recordset to dataset because while 200 more data load to datagridview that after datagrid has been very slow, so i want my code change to load datagrid by dataset but i dont know dataset code how to merge multiple field of database data into one column in datagrid, So please help me...

```
Private Sub FLEX1_LOAD()
      DataGridView1.Rows.Clear() 
      Dim strsql As String
      Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset
      strsql = "select * from voterlist where AREAID='" & Trim(lblAreaid.Text) & "'"
      rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
      Call dbconnect2()
      rs2.Open(strsql,conne2,ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic,ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockPessimistic)
      If rs2.RecordCount > 0 Then
       rs2.MoveFirst()
       For I = 0 To rs2.RecordCount - 1
          DataGridView1.Rows.Add(1)
          DataGridView1.Rows(J).Cells(0).Value = J + 1
          DataGridView1.Rows(J).Cells(1).Value =rs2.Fields("ID").Value
          DataGridView1.Rows(J).Cells(2).Value = rs2.Fields("NAM").Value & " " & rs2.Fields("SURNAME").Value & "/" & rs2.Fields("RTYPE").Value & "-" & rs2.Fields("RNAME").Value & " " & rs2.Fields("RSURNAME").Value
          DataGridView1.Rows(J).Cells(3).Value = rs2.Fields("AGE").Value
          J = J + 1
          rs2.MoveNext()
       Next
      End If
      rs2.Close()
      rs2 = Nothing
      conne2.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not simply combine the columns you want combined in your SQL code?  That seems to be the glaringly obvious thing to do.

Comment: Example ? @jmcilhinney

Comment: @MantuSwain `SELECT YourField1 + ' ' + YourField2 as NewName...`?

Comment: @CrushSundae Thank you, its working by oleDb method, but here again a question- if result of oledb 'SEX'= 1 Then how to auto view in datagrid 'SEX'="M" at a time of loading datagridview.

Comment: @MantuSwain, Comments section is not meant for extended discussions. But to make your day, you can also use your query. Read about [CaseWhen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). It's like the `If` statement in `VB` so you'll much likely to understand it.